# Let $U \in U(H)$ be unitary operator on Hilbert space $H$. Is it possible for it to has an empty point spectrum?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $U\in U(H)$ be unitary operator. Is it possible for it to has an empty point spectrum?

I am aware that every bounded operator acting on complex Hilbert space has non-empty spectrum.

Since $\forall \lVert v \rVert = 1$ we have

$$\lVert Uv \rVert ^2 = \langle Uv, Uv\rangle = \langle U^*Uv, v \rangle = \lVert v \rVert ^2 = 1$$

It means that indeed $\sigma{(U)} \neq \emptyset$.

The question is how can I prove such thing without definition of resolvent and Liouville's theorem?

Comment: I don't know if it answers your question, but consider $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots\}$ a Hilbert basis and $U(e_j) = e_{j+1}$.  $U$ is then unitary (edit : is it?) but I don't think it would have any eigenvector.

Comment: @DIdier_ that is not a unitary (it not surjective). It is the adjoint of the forward unilateral shift, and it has every complex number of modulus <1 as an eigenvalue (although it’s adjoint has no eigenvalues). In infinite dimensions, eigenvalues don’t make up the spectrum completely.

Comment: Is the question whether $U$ can have empty spectrum or wether one can prove that the spectrum is non-empty without resolvent and Liouville?

Comment: @PStheman thanks for the precision!

Comment: @G.Chiusole Yes, the question is can unitary operator have empty point spectrum?

Comment: So you are specifically asking about the **point** spectrum?

Comment: @G.Chiusole Yes, sorry I should have stated it at the begining, but this is due to the fact that my professor is using the same symbol for point spectrum. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are many well-known unitaries with empty point spectrum. For instance consider $H=L^2(\mathbb T)$, with Lebesgue measure, and $U$ the operator given by 
$$
(Uf)(z)=zf(z). 
$$
As $|z|=1$ for all $z$, it is easy to see that $U$ is isometric and that $U^*U=UU^*=I$. It is easy to check that $\sigma(U)=\mathbb T$, and that it has no eigenvalues.

The argument you give to claim that any unitary has non-empty spectrum does not prove anything. You could have used it to prove the same over a real Hilbert space, where it is not true: the unitary 
$$
U=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix} \in B(\mathbb R^2)
$$
has empty spectrum. So to prove that the spectrum is nonempty, you have to use that your field is $\mathbb C$ in an essential way. You will not be able to avoid either the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, Liouville, or some other similar theorem.